Remove an element from HTML using Javascript
I am working from a backend system, which doesn't allow me to edit the HTML but does allow me to add javascript or HTML And CSS in the top or bottom of the page.
I have the following code on the page:
<div class="ext_ui_section_items"><div class="ext_ui_dropdown_item ext_ui_dropdown_item--light"><a href="/user/approvals" tabindex="0" class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_anchor"><div class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_anchor_wrapper"><span class="ext_ui_dropdown_icon_wrapper"><!----></span> <span class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_text">
    Approvals
    </span> <span class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_suffix"><div data-v-2032d9d2="" data-ui-id="countValue" class="badge menu_style_light">
  0
</div></span></div></a></div> <div class="ext_ui_dropdown_item ext_ui_dropdown_item--light" data-ui-id="my-requests"><a href="/user/requests?reporter=ALL_REQUESTS" tabindex="0" class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_anchor"><div class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_anchor_wrapper"><span class="ext_ui_dropdown_icon_wrapper"><!----></span> <span class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_text">
    My requests
    </span> <span class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_suffix"><div data-v-2032d9d2="" data-ui-id="countValue" class="badge menu_style_light">
  0
</div></span></div></a></div></div>

Now the element I want to remove is the FIRST child element in that list named 'ext_ui_dropdown_item ext_ui_dropdown_item--light' by class, however, I do not want to remove the entire list, but just that first index. The issue I have is, that they are both named with the same class and removing one removes both of them. Can anyone help?
I have tried
 const parent = document.getElementsByClassName("ext_ui_section_items");
    const child = document.getElementsByClassName("ext_ui_dropdown_item ext_ui_dropdown_item--light");

setting the constants and then trying to remove them via the HTML collection, but it's confusing me now.

Where's your code that's removing the elements?

Here is the JS code to remove the first element from a list:


// Get the parent element
var parent = document.querySelector('.ext_ui_section_items');

// Get the first child element with the specified class
var elementToRemove = parent.querySelector('.ext_ui_dropdown_item.ext_ui_dropdown_item--light');

// Check if the element exists before attempting to remove it
if (elementToRemove) {
    // Remove the first element from a list
    parent.removeChild(elementToRemove);
}
<div class="ext_ui_section_items">
   <div class="ext_ui_dropdown_item ext_ui_dropdown_item--light">
      <a href="/user/approvals" tabindex="0" class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_anchor">
         <div class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_anchor_wrapper">
            <span class="ext_ui_dropdown_icon_wrapper">
               <!---->
            </span>
            <span class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_text">
            Approvals
            </span> 
            <span class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_suffix">
               <div data-v-2032d9d2="" data-ui-id="countValue" class="badge menu_style_light">
                  0
               </div>
            </span>
         </div>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="ext_ui_dropdown_item ext_ui_dropdown_item--light" data-ui-id="my-requests">
      <a href="/user/requests?reporter=ALL_REQUESTS" tabindex="0" class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_anchor">
         <div class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_anchor_wrapper">
            <span class="ext_ui_dropdown_icon_wrapper">
               <!---->
            </span>
            <span class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_text">
            My requests
            </span> 
            <span class="ext_ui_dropdown_item_suffix">
               <div data-v-2032d9d2="" data-ui-id="countValue" class="badge menu_style_light">
                  0
               </div>
            </span>
         </div>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>



Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp

I tried that and I get
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')

In that case, you need to check if the element exists first. Make sure you run the script when the page is successfully loaded.

It works if I paste it in console once the page has loaded. Can we put a wait in for the page to load? Also it's getting rid of the first element not the second, sorry to be a pain and this has helped me A LOT!!


I fixed it by doing this
